# unwanted tables created in Lightswitch

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am creating a simple Lightswitch application and recently it started to create additional tables and views in my database.

It creates following tables:

- aspnet_Applications
- aspnet_Membership
- aspnet_Profile
- aspnet_Roles
- aspnet_SchemaVersions
- aspnet_Users
- aspnet_UsersInRoles

The deal is that i do not use any kind of authentication in my app and I use a static database login for working with data. Can the creation of these tables be avoided? 
Their creation began spontaneously, everything worked fine without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using an *attached database*? The following comments assume that you are.

If you're using LS 2011, then at some stage you must have pointed the *deploy wizard* at the same database that you attached, instead of letting it create a new database for its *intrinsic* data.

If you're using the RC of LS 2012, then I remember hearing that there was some kind of bug that involved the creation of the asp_* tables. This should be fixed in the RTM (final) version of LS 2012.